# Don't the expression need to be faster for getting a property value than the reflection?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, expression

I know that the using expression is faster for a getting property value than the using reflection, I would like to convert list to datatable, I have used both of them,

**The reflection elapsed time** : 36 ms

**The expression elapsed time** : 2350 ms

I wonder I am doing something wrong there?

I have tried below code :

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public long IntCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = new Random();
            var foos = new List<Foo>();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                foos.Add(new Foo { IntCode = r.Next(), Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), SurName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = r.Next() });
            }
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time For Creating : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();
            ConvertWithReflection(foos, "IntCode", "Name", "Age");
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time For Converting : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw.Restart();
            ConvertWithExpression(foos, "IntCode", "Name", "Age");
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time For Converting : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static object GetValueGetter<T>(object item,string propertyName)
        {
            var arg = Expression.Parameter(item.GetType(), "x");
            Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
            var unaryExpression = Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(object));
            var propertyResolver = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(unaryExpression, arg).Compile();
            var value = propertyResolver((T)item);
            return value;
        }

        public static void ConvertWithReflection<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, params string[] columnNames)
        {
            var t = list.ToList();
            if (!t.Any()) return;
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("IntCode");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("SurName");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Age");
            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    var el = columnNames.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
                    if (el == null)
                    {
                        dr[i] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var property =  item.GetType().GetProperty(el);
                        dr[i] = property.GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        public static void ConvertWithExpression<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, params string[] columnNames)
        {
            var t = list.ToList();
            if (!t.Any()) return;
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("IntCode");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("SurName");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Age");
            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    var el = columnNames.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
                    if (el == null)
                    {
                        dr[i] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[i] = GetValueGetter<T>(item, el);
                    }
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think expressions should be faster? Expressions use reflection... What can be faster is to generate and cache a delegate and reuse it, but your code is rebuilding and compiling a delegate every time, which takes a lot of time.

Comment: I understand, I don't know how to cache it, can you make a sample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing apples to apples: your expression code constructs and compiles an expression on each iteration, producing a fair amount of throw-away activity at each iteration. Reflection code, on the other hand, uses all the optimizations that the designers of the CLR have put into the system, performing only the necessary operations.

Essentially, you are comparing Preparation time + Working time for expressions vs. Working time for reflection. This is not the intended way of using expressions in situations when an action is repeated 10,000 times: you are expected to prepare and compile your lambdas upfront, store them in a cache of some sort, and then quickly retrieve them as needed on each iteration. Implementing some sort of caching would even out your comparison:

```
public static object GetValueGetter<T>(object item, string propertyName, IDictionary<string,Func<T,object>> cache) {
    Func<T, object> propertyResolver;
    if (!cache.TryGetValue(propertyName, out propertyResolver)) {
        var arg = Expression.Parameter(item.GetType(), "x");
        Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
        var unaryExpression = Expression.Convert(expr, typeof (object));
        propertyResolver = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(unaryExpression, arg).Compile();
        cache.Add(propertyName, propertyResolver);
    }
    return propertyResolver((T)item);
}
```

call looks like this:

```
var cache = new Dictionary<string,Func<T,object>>();
foreach (var item in t) {
    var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++) {
        var el = columnNames.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
        if (el == null) {
            dr[i] = DBNull.Value;
        } else {
            dr[i] = GetValueGetter<T>(item, el, cache);
        }
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Now that the costs of preparation are spread across 10,000 calls, reflections becomes the slower of the three methods:

```
Elapsed Time For Creating : 29
Elapsed Time For Converting : 84  <-- Reflection
Elapsed Time For Converting : 53  <-- Expressions
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand exactly, It need to be cached for each property.

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling the expression repeatedly. Compile it once and it will be faster.

If compiling an expression every time was faster the runtime would do it automatically.